# How to insert data into named graph using SPARQL?

Tags: python, sparql, triplestore, sparqlwrapper, triples

I am using python to insert data into blazegraph. I want to specify the named graph to which the data gets inserted, but the code I am using is triggering the error:

```
SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed.
```

How can I solve this error and insert data into the given named graph?

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, TURTLE, RDFXML

query='''
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

INSERT DATA {
    GRAPH <http://example/shelf_A> {
        <http://example/author> dcterms:name "author" .

        <http://example/book> dcterms:title "book" ;
                              dcterms:author <http://example/author> .  
    } 
}
'''

sparql =SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/namespace/kb/sparql")

sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.method = 'POST'
sparql.query()
```

I also tried running this query from the update tab of blazegraph and the same error happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `QueryBadFormed` - the endpoint thinks you have sent a query, In SPARQL Queries and Updates are different. They have different keywords. 

For example, it's "?update=" not "?query=" and this then lets the received decide which kind of operation it is.

Other systems use different URLs for query and update.

Comment: @AndyS so how could I change the query or the code then?

Comment: You can't change the string - SPARQL query is read-only. The documentation for SPARQLWrapper and BlazeGraph (or search StackOveflow) should help - I don't know the details.